# Java Swing - How to bind a JComponent in Netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, netbeans, binding

I am using Netbeans Swing GUI builder to design my app's GUI. I have a `JTextField tf` and a `JCheckBox cb`.

Now, I want that the `tf` is enabled only when the `cb` is both enabled and selected.

I am performing the below steps to perform this in Netbeans:

1. Right click on `tf` >> Properties >> Binding
2. Click on button `...` at the right of `enabled`
3. Binding Source: tf

   Binding Expression: ${selected}

Now, in the above steps, binding expression can be set either to `${selected}` or to `${enabled}`.

But according to my needs, the binding expression should be something like `${selected} && ${enabled}`.

I tried the above expression too but it didn't work.

How can I do that through Netbeans?

Comment: Why don't you learn to do it through writing your own code so you aren't dependent on an IDE to write the code for you? The next company you work for may use a different IDE. Spend time learning skills that are transferable.

Comment: I think you meant text field's binding source to be the checkbox, not itself.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you want is,

```
${enabled && selected}
```

Type the expression manually into the field.

You must do one additional thing. Go to the *Advanced* tab, and change the *Update Mode* from **Read/write** to **Read-Only**. Otherwise, the disablement of the text field will also disable the checkbox.

Comment: Which Advanced tab you are talking about?

Comment: From the Bindings dialog, in the sub-dialog for editing the "enabled" binding, there is an Advanced tab. At least, on NetBeans 6.7, the version I'm using.